# Is their a way to add a delay between messages processing in apache camel(activemq)

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel

1. Application1: source system sending 10 requests per sec to apache camel(ActiveMQ).
2. Application2: Apache camel which receives request from Application1 and sends it to downstream system Application3(10 requests/sec).
3. Application3: The downstream system(post API) gets 10 requests per sec from apache camel and processes the request.

Problem statement: Application3 has DB updates and processing tasks to be handled because of the 10 requests at a time to application3 the duplicates are been generated during processing and DB updates.

Please suggest the way I can add a delay of 1sec between each request either at apache camel /the downstream system.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you should not add delay nor on your service bus nor on your consumer. What about immediately acknowledging and stacking messages in a HashSet collection then implementing batch updates of that list of entities ?

Comment: The question is why you get duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Delay EIP](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/delay-eip.html) in Camel you can use to delay every message (probably in Application 2) for a fixed or even calculated amount of time. Make sure that you only have 1 Consumer in Application 2.

There is also a [Throttle EIP](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/throttle-eip.html) in Camel, but it keeps all messages that are hold back in memory. In your case it is better to slow down the consumption of Application 2 to avoid overloading Application 3.

I guess that Application 3 get duplicates because it can't keep up with the requests and then Application 2 gets Timeouts and its error handling sends the requests again.

However, when you use messaging, you have to prepare for duplicates. In error cases you can easily receive duplicates and therefore you have to make Application 3 idempotent.

Of course, Camel can also help you with this thanks to the [Idempotent Consumer](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/idempotentConsumer-eip.html).